# CalendarPicker view shows me one day early dates

Tags: android, calendar

I have used the calendar picker view in my android application from the following GitHub repo.

square/android-times-square

Now in almost all devices, it shows me proper weekdays as per the date, but in few devices like Samsung, Lenovo it shoes me the one day early for the week, for example, if today is 30-05-2018 Wednesday, then it will show me Tuesday on 30-05-2018.

[image]